# Yii1 - Cookie for website inside web service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii

We have a SOAP web-service in Yii1 that's part of a web site #1, and we're working on implementing a sort of SSO where site #2 of ours can receive a cookie from the site #1 via web service. The stumbling block here is how to log into the website and extract a cookie for user being logged in.

One way I can think of is to send CURL request to web site and extract cookies from the response, sending them back. Although that's clunky, I can't seem to find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, we've found that Yii returns a cookie in response' headers when making a call to the webs-service that's inside said website.